# Excel VBA out of memory

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an Excel VBA out of memory 007 error. I'm using efficiencies to clear clipboard, memory, memory usage restrictions and still get it on my GetData(integer) function the second time it is called. Any ideas? I am forced to run 32 bit on my govt computer.

```
Sub RunStatusOfFunds()

    'Declare worksheet variables
    Dim HOME As Worksheet
    Dim CRIS_CRITERIA_DATASHEET As Worksheet
    Dim DEAMS_CRITERIA_DATASHEET As Worksheet
    Dim CRITERIA_INSTRUCTIONS As Worksheet
    Dim DEAMS_DATASHEET As Worksheet
    Dim CRIS_DATASHEET As Worksheet
    Dim VSF_DATASHEET As Worksheet
    Dim CALCULATIONS As Worksheet
    Dim STATUS As Chart
    Dim VSF_DEAMS As Worksheet
    Dim VSF_CRIS As Worksheet

    'Set variables to actual worksheets
    Set HOME = Sheets("Home")
    Set CRIS_CRITERIA_DATASHEET = Sheets("CRIS_CRITERIA_DATASHEET")
    Set DEAMS_CRITERIA_DATASHEET = Sheets("DEAMS_CRITERIA_DATASHEET")
    Set CRITERIA_INSTRUCTIONS = Sheets("CRITERIA_INSTRUCTIONS")
    Set DEAMS_DATASHEET = Sheets("DEAMS_DATASHEET")
    Set CRIS_DATASHEET = Sheets("CRIS_DATASHEET")
    Set VSF_DATASHEET = Sheets("VSF_DATASHEET")
    Set CALCULATIONS = Sheets("CALCULATIONS")
    Set STATUS = Charts("STATUS")
    Set VSF_DEAMS = Sheets("VSF_DEAMS")
    Set VSF_CRIS = Sheets("VSF_CRIS")

    'Declare working variables such as counters, etc.
    Dim z, n As Integer

    'Declare arrays to hold data from tables
    Dim DEAMS_data_array(0 To 67) As Variant
    Dim DCriteria_data_array(0 To 9) As Variant
    Dim CRIS_data_array(0 To 67) As Variant
    Dim CCriteria_data_array() As Variant

    'Declare location variables
    Dim ppLocation As String
    Dim ptLocation As String

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    UnlockSheets            'Use password to unlock all sheets

    'Request file locations
    ppLocation = HOME.Cells(19, 11)
    ptLocation = HOME.Cells(21, 11)

    VSF_DEAMS.Range("A:Z").Clear
    VSF_CRIS.Range("A:Z").Clear
    DEAMS_DATASHEET.Range("A:Z").Clear
    CRIS_DATASHEET.Range("A:Z").Clear

    'Get DEAMS data
    z = 0
    z = GetData(0)

    If z = 1 Then
        CancelUpdate            'If no data given exit
        LockSheets              'Lock sheets
        HOME.Select             'Change user visual focus to Home
        Exit Sub
    End If

    VSF_CRIS.Cells.Clear

    'Get CRIS data
    z = 0
    z = GetData(1)

    If z = 1 Then
        CancelUpdate        'If no data given exit
        LockSheets              'Lock sheets
        HOME.Select             'Change user visual focus to Home
    End If

    'Copy DEAMS data
    'Collect DEAMS headers
    n = 1
    For i = 0 To 67
        DEAMS_data_array(i) = DEAMS_DATASHEET.Cells(1, n)
        n = n + 1
    Next i

    n = 1
    For i = 0 To 67
        CRIS_data_array(i) = CRIS_DATASHEET.Cells(1, n)
        n = n + 1
    Next i

    'Write DEAMS headers, add Description
    'VSF_DEAMS.Activate
    'VSF_DEAMS.Cells.Clear
    'VSF_DEAMS.Cells(1, 1).Activate
    VSF_DEAMS.Cells(1, 1).Value = "DESCRIPTION"
    VSF_CRIS.Cells(1, 1).Value = "DESCRIPTION"

    n = 2
    For i = 0 To 67
        VSF_DEAMS.Cells(1, n).Value = DEAMS_data_array(i)
        n = n + 1
    Next i

    n = 2
    For i = 0 To 67
        VSF_CRIS.Cells(1, n) = CRIS_data_array(i)
        n = n + 1
    Next i

    Call findDesc(DEAMS_DATASHEET, DEAMS_CRITERIA_DATASHEET, VSF_DEAMS)
    Call findDesc(CRIS_DATASHEET, CRIS_CRITERIA_DATASHEET, VSF_CRIS)

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub UnlockSheets()

    If Sheets("HOME").Cells(26, 6).Value = "Sheet is Unlocked" Then Exit Sub

    Set CrisData = Sheets("CRIS_DATASHEET")
    Set DEAMSData = Sheets("DEAMS_DATASHEET")
    Set VSFData = Sheets("VSF_DATASHEET")

    With CrisData                                                   'Unlock spreadsheets
        .Unprotect Password:="pass"
        .Cells.Locked = False
    End With

    With DEAMSData
        .Unprotect Password:="pass"
        .Cells.Locked = False
    End With
    With VSFData
        .Unprotect Password:="pass"
        .Cells.Locked = False
    End With
    With Sheets("HOME")
        .Unprotect Password:="pass"
        .Cells.Locked = False
    End With

    Sheets("HOME").Select
    Sheets("HOME").Cells(26, 6).Value = "Sheet is Unlocked"

End Sub

Public Function GetData(loc As Integer) As Integer

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim raw As Workbook, ThisBook As Workbook
    Dim fileName

    'Opens the data sheet from which to work from

    Set ThisBook = ThisWorkbook

    If loc = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please select DEAM's Discoverer Viewer export")
        'Get the DEAMS File
        fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
        , "Please select DEAM's Discoverer Viewer STATUS_OF_FUNDS Excel Output")
        If fileName = False Then
            GetData = 1
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set raw = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
        raw.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        raw.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please select CRIS export")
        'Get the CRIS File
        fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
        , "Please select CRIS export")
        If fileName = False Then
            GetData = 1
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set raw = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    End If



    If loc = 0 Then
    ThisBook.Sheets("DEAMS_DATASHEET").Range("A:V").Value = raw.Sheets(1).Range("A:V").Value

    Else
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    raw.Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").Unlist
    raw.Sheets(1).Range("A:Z").ClearFormats
    ThisBook.Sheets("CRIS_DATASHEET").Range("A:X").Value = raw.Sheets(1).Range("A:X").Value

    End If

    raw.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set ThisBook = Nothing
    Set raw = Nothing
    GetDeamsData = 0

End Function
```

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You've pasted a 'wall of code' that no one can reproduce without building a multiple worksheet workbook from scratch.

Comment: You've also included passwords - is this wise (particularly for USAF)?

Comment: This is not secure data. The passwords are only so that no one screws up the worksheet.

Comment: I added the "wall of code" because of the suggestions on previous error 7 posts that suggested the need to see "the whole picture" to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Out of memory means there is not enough contigious memory for some structure/object/thing. It does not mean there is no free memory, or even a lot of free memory, just not in a block large enough. Therefore look at the data you have that are large.

Also I imagine this code is run from inside excel. Think about taking it into vbscript or VB6. Then each datasheet can live in it's own process (then each datasheet will have lots of memory space to fit into) as calls will be out of process. This is slow.

I would imagine your process design is faulty. You are opening at the same time a lot of stuff.

Comment: Thank you for bringing me out of the fog on the out of memory error. I was wondering, even in 32bit how I was chewing up 1.3gb of memory.